# Is it possible to get into Psychology research after a PhD in HCI (human computer interaction)?

Tags: career-path, changing-fields, psychology

I'm very interested in psychology research, especially exploring patterns and reason of behaviour, and mechanisms of human mind. During my PhD, I spent considerable amount of time exploring cognitive and neuropsychology literature, and conducted quite a few behavioural and user studies. I'm very confident of my skills in designing experiments and statistics.

**My questions are:**

1. Is it possible to be employed by a psychology department merely with
   these skills and knowledge?
2. Should I rather try other types of jobs
   which could compromise between my interest and skills?

A little bit more about my background: I did one-year taught master course in *psychology*, but both my undergraduate and PhD were in *computer science* departments.

Comment: I know of some people who did that in Germany - so the answer is "yes"!

Comment: There is a subfield in HCI called human factors engineering. It comes under psych and engineering ,as human factors involves ethnography. You may want to look into that

Comment: Here is something what could you do with your CS degree in psychology http://www.economist.com/news/science-and-technology/21612114-virtual-shrink-may-sometimes-be-better-real-thing-computer-will-see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've met people who were Computer Science PhDs and actually were part of Psychology departments.

If you did HCI, I think it gets harder to do Psychology, after all is a whole study area by itself, since yours was more specific.

My advice would be to find a laboratory that has both of them, and that way you can get involved in some projects so you can learn other things about psychology

I do not presume to know about the filed, but I'm guessing there are multiple laboratories that might have a psychologist as well as a computer scientists.

Essentially, build up your creed as a Psychologist by going somewhere where there is interaction between the two fields.